# Bash script to update Deluged Interface IP fails to run as cron job, but works when run manually

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I'm running a Debian Linux variant, OpenVPN, and Deluge.
My VPN provider has short IP leases, so every few days I need to update Deluge's interface IP so that it downloads only on tun0. I put together a script to automate this - it basically puts the current tun0 IP into $tun0ip, then does a grep check against the deluge daemon config file to see if that string is present (this is a dirty way to do it, but I guess it works).

My problem is this: When I call the script manually, it works as intended - it kills deluged and then relaunches it, specifying the new IP with `deluged -i $tun0ip` . However, when I run the script as a cron job, it fails - it passes a null or zero value to $tun0ip, and then `deluged -i $tun0ip` doesn't work without a valid IP specified, so the application fails to launch. Script below. Am I doing something wrong here? I really appreciate any help!

```
#!/bin/bash

tun0ip=$( ifconfig tun0 | grep -Eo 'inet (addr:)?([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*' |   grep -Eo '([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*' | grep -v '127.0.0.1')

if grep -q $tun0ip "/root/.config/deluge/core.conf"; then
#Great, the IP is correct - don't have to do anything.
echo "IP Looks good - no changes were made."
else
echo "tun0 IP not found in config file. Killing deluged and rebooting with $tun0ip as interface."
killall deluged
sleep 5
deluged -i $tun0ip

fi
```

Comment: Cron jobs do not run the user's init scripts so there may be stuff missing on the path, so perhapse ifconfig is not available and tun0ip is null. Make it pipe errors to a log file while you debug the kinks.

Comment: Ok, this lead me in the right direction, in addition to this post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/616406/ifdown-in-cron-bash-script-fails-to-run

I had to specifiy /sbin/ifconfig, like this:
tun0ip=$( /sbin/ifconfig tun0 | grep -Eo 'inet (addr:)?([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*' | grep -Eo '([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*'$
#delugedinterface=$(grep expression for deluged.conf IP)

Comment: This is the most common thing I have run into when helping people run their "working" scripts as crons :) Glad it got you there.

Answer (score 0):

I had to specifiy /sbin/ifconfig, like this:

```
tun0ip=$( /sbin/ifconfig tun0 | grep -Eo 'inet (addr:)?([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*' | grep -Eo '([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*'$
```